# JavaScript constructor functions - understanding inheritance

Tags: javascript

I am learning how to implement OOP in JavaScript using constructor functions, and I am facing some confusion regarding how sub types are created.

My current understanding is, the new keyword is what works behind the scenes to do the following:

- create an empty `this` object
- set the `__proto__` property of the `this` object to point to the prototype property on the constructor function
- return the `this` object

That is why we do not have to explicitly return an object from our constructor function, the `new` keyword does it for us.

In the example below I am creating a `PaidUser` sub type of the `User` type:

```
function User(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

function PaidUser(name, balance) {
  User.call(this, name);
  this.balance = balance;
}
```

Following examples I have seen, I am extending from the `User` types properties in the `PaidUser` type and setting the context of `this` in the `User` constructor to point to the lexical `this` with `User.call(this,...)`

My confusion is regarding how does `User.call()` affect what is implicitly returned by the `new` keyword from the `PaidUser` constructor?

For example in the `PaidUser` constructor i define the `this.balance` property to the `this` object, now it is my understanding it is the `this` object which will be returned from the `PaidUser` constructor, when called with the `new` keyword. How does `User.call(this, name)` ever get returned or effect the object returned from the `PaidUser` constructor.

Currently according to my understanding, this is what imagine is sort of happening behind the scenes:

```
function PaidUser(name, balance) {
  this = {
  __proto__:PaidUser.prototype
  };
  this.balance = balance;
  User.call(this, name); // {this.name:name}; //lexical this
                         // why is the object returned from User.call() just floating around
                         // neither assigned to a variable or returned ?

  return this;  // how does this.name ever become part of the returned object?
}
```

I would really appreciate any help and explanation regarding the steps taken by the `new` keyword when when the `PaidUser` constructor function is called.

With much thanks and appreciation.

Comment: `User.call(this, name)` explicitly makes `this` in the `User()` function be the **same** `this` that the `new` call to `PaidUser` created.

Comment: I think I understand, when we call `User.call(this,name)` it calls the User function and sets the name property on the PaidUser `this` object? I guess i got lost in all the constructor creation specifics and forgot to remember we are infact calling a function with User.call() Thankyou very much!

Comment: call can create multiple objects with the same scope.

Comment: The `new` keyword basically does this: `function customNew(Constructor, ...args) { const obj = Object.create(Constructor.prototype); const result = Constructor.apply(obj, args); return result && typeof result === 'object' ? result : obj;)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My confusion is regarding how does `User.call()` affect what is implicitly returned by the `new` keyword from the `PaidUser` constructor?

The key to understanding how that happens is understanding that objects that are passed into a function can be affected outside of it:

```js
//function that takes an object and mutates it
function fn(o) {
  o.hello = "universe";
}

//a simple object
var obj = {
  hello: "world"
};

console.log("before calling the function", obj);

//call the function with the object
fn(obj);

console.log("after calling the function", obj);
```

So, objects can be mutated inside functions and it affects them outside the function, too.

This is also what happens when you invoke `User.call(this, name);` the body of the `User` constructor function is `this.name = name` which mutates the `this` context. Since the `this` context is an object, it will be mutated outside of the function. And since it mutates the `this` context of `new PaidUser` effectively the code does this:

```
function PaidUser(name, balance) {
  this.name = name; //contents of User.call(this, name);
  this.balance = balance;
}
```

So, it's actually a lot less magical than it seems. The only part the `new` keyword plays in the entire process is that `new PaidUser` will create a new object and set it as the `this` context. You can emulate a similar effect by doing the following:

```js
function User(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

function PaidUser(name, balance) {
  User.call(this, name);
  this.balance = balance;
}

var obj = {};

PaidUser.call(obj, "Fred", 1234);

console.log(obj);
```

This doesn't do everything the `new` keyword does - it won't set the prototype, not make the constructor function implicitly return `this`, but it still creates a new object and puts it through all the assignments. Since we have reference to the object, we can examine it afterwards and see that indeed the code has *effectively* done `obj.name = name` and `obj.balance = balance`.

Comment: Basically what I wanted to write. I would add that objects are *reference type* values (and mutable) which is why mutating them inside a function affects them outside the function. There are languages where that is not the case (e.g. PHP arrays). Also see my comment on the question for a user space `new` function.

Comment: @VLAZ I understand perfectly now, thank you for the detailed explanation, it has really reinforced my understanding. In truth I got lost in the specifics of the `new` keyword, and as you mentioned, made it to be more 'magical' than it is. And failed to realize we are just mutating the `this` object by calling User.call(this,name) --Many thanks for your help